# Which human character killed the most Kingsguard members?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Who killed the most Kingsguards/Queensguards? I know that in the second-to-last episode of the TV show,

> Sandor Clegane killed quite a few, at least 4 and maybe 5 if you include former Kingsguards (suicide to kill his brother).

Specifications: the character must have killed the guard themselves, not others who did it for them; former Kingsguards do count, if it influences the answer.

I'd appreciate an answer from both the books and the show.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### **In the books, Rupert Falwell, Loras Tyrell, or possibly Ned Stark.**

[Rupert Falwell](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rupert_Falwell), or the Fighting Fool, was a historical character who killed **two** Kingsguard at the [Battle of the Great Fork](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_the_Great_Fork) during the Faith Militant uprising.

If we're counting "unofficial" Kingsguard such as Renly's [Rainbow Guard](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rainbow_Guard), then Loras Tyrell makes the list for killing **two** of his own Kingsguard after they failed to prevent Renly's death.

In the [fight at the Tower of Joy](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Combat_at_the_tower_of_joy), it's never made explicit exactly who killed who. Since Ned and Howland were the only survivors, it's reasonable to assume they killed **at least one or two** of the Kingsguard.

As far as I know, nobody in the books is known for sure to have killed more than two Kingsguard.

### In the show, Sandor Clegane.

As you note, [the Hound killed](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Kingsguard) four of Cersei Lannister's Queensguard plus one former Kingsguard all by himself, making him easily the victor of the Kingsguard Killer kompetition in *Game of Thrones*.

See also:

Comment: Hmm actually according to the wiki link there were 3 Kingsguard. So either Ned and/or Howland could have killed between 1 and 3.

Comment: @Amarth or one of the people who died could have taken out a kingsguard

Comment: @Termatinator Yes that's what I meant but the survivors must have killed at least 1. And it could have been either Ned or Howland who killed all 3.

Comment: @Amarth Yep, that's why I said *possibly* Ned Stark. We don't have enough information to know if he beats/equals the other two or not. (I'm assuming Ned killed more than Howland simply because Ned is supposed to be one of the best fighters in the realm and Howland isn't spoken of as such.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor In both books and TV series is clearly stated that, without Rownland's help, Ned would have been killed. Maybe it was him dealing the killing blow, so your answer is correct, but George RR Martin himself said that while Ned was a competent fighter he wasn't in the top rankings.

Answer (score 2):

If looking at the timeline of the books only (*A Game of Thrones* up to *A Dance with Dragons*), ignoring past events/history and considering only the Kings-/Queensguard of the monarch in King's Landing - disregarding the various guards installed by contenders Daenerys, Renly or Aegon, then it is:

- Areo Hotah, who killed Arys Oakheart.

Nobody else kills a Kingsguard in combat throughout the books.

Comment: Do the mob who kill Ser Preston Greenfield not count? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, we don't know who exactly it was who killed him.